# When you read/write to a cache, at what level is that information?

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

Assume the following block of code in a C#/ASP.net environment:

```
// Read from the cache
object value = Cache["key"];
// Add a new item to the cache
Cache["key"] = value;
Cache.Insert(key, value);
Cache.Insert(key, value, CacheDependency);
Cache.Insert(key, value, CacheDependency, DateTime, TimeSpan);
```

Now, assume an IE9 browser with 3 different tabs open.

Is that cache item available to each tab?  Any future tabs that are opened?  Or is it just available to the tab that has the webpage that creates it?

Answer (score 4):

First, `Cache` are server sides, second it is shared among all the users of that web server, so as many users as you have, they will share the same `Cache` object irrespective of the browser.

See: [ASP.NET Caching Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178597(v=vs.140).aspx)

Comment: Well, the cache is shared among all users *of that web server*.  The site may be supported by multiple servers behind a load balancer, so you cannot rely on all users having access to the same cache.